# Samsung Gear application on the phone does not detect smartwatch

Tags: android, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-gear

When I enable bluetooth on the phone, it finds the smartwatch and pairs successfully. However, when going to the samsung app 'samsung gear manager' it says 'no devices found'. This is the initial setup of the smartwatch and I cannot continue to initialization because it does not work without this app running on the phone. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To make the watch and phone pair, you only use the Samsung Gear Manager. Probably the reason it's not showing up is because of the existing BT connection you've made. Disconnect and Forget the watch in the Bluetooth Settings, then go back to Gear Manager.

You may need to go into the Watch Settings and choose Bluetooth to get it to go back into discovery mode.

Comment: Hi Eric, I turned off bluetooth on the phone. Then go to 'samsung gear' and press scan. It turns on the bluetooth and searches for a few seconds and still says there are no devices found. So it's not connected via bluetooth before I open it. What else could be the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't turn off Bluetooth. Go into the Bluetooth Settings and find the device that you've paired using Bluetooth. The Gear watch should show up in that list along side any other BT devices you have. http://imgur.com/Kr2p0i2 Tap on the gear to bring up the properties for that device and choose 'Unpair'. http://imgur.com/aXN45Wb

Comment: I tried that many times. Is it possible Android 4.3+ is needed for this app to work?

Comment: Yes. Android 4.3 and higher is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I called Samsung. Samsung Galaxy Ace is not compatible with Gear2.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to download the Gear Fir Manager from apps.samsung.com/gearfit not from the samsung app store.
The Samsung app store version does not work, you need to download the latest gear app from the website, gd luck